# I have SharePoint list for IT support ticketing, can I manage status section on the form to be edit only by specific user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions

Can I set permission on this SharePoint list, so only me or IT team can edit but another user only add items and view no edit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can self-create a permission level that removes the permission to edit items in the list.

1.Click on the gear icon above > Site permissions > Advanced permissions settings > Permission levels.

[image]

2.You can click Create Permission Levels to select the permissions you need, just edit the permissions to leave them unchecked.
Or you can copy the currently existing permission level (Click on an existing permission to click the Copy Permission Level button at the end of the page.) and remove the edit permission.

[image]

[image]

[image]

3.Click on the gear icon above > List Settings > Permissions for this list.

4.Stop inheriting permissions and then give your users permission levels that you created yourself.
[image]

5.In the list, users without editing privileges will have icons that cannot be edited.

[image]